# cURL not redirecting properly

Tags: php, post, redirect, curl

I've read a lot of cURL questions on here and none of them seem to have had the same problem I am having.

I have a form set up to submit the following:

```
if(isset($_POST['submitted_form']) && $_POST['submitted_form'] == "yes"){
    $ch = curl_init("https://www.pipelinedeals.com/web_lead");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, "http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']."");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "developer_mode=".$_POST['developer_mode']."&thank_you_page=".$_POST['thank_you_page']."&w2lid=".$_POST['w2lid']."&assign_to_id=".$_POST['assign_to_id']."&lead[lead_source]=".$_POST['lead[lead_source]']."&lead[full_name]=".$_POST['lead[full_name]']."&lead[phone]=".$_POST['lead[phone]']."&lead[email]=".$_POST['lead[email]']."");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
}
```

Before anyone asks why I am using such a convoluted method to post the data, rather than just submitting the form, it is because I want to use the data for some other purposes before passing it on to PipelineDeals.

It's so close to working properly I can taste it. My problem is that when I run the code on say "http://exampledomain.com" it goes ahead and posts the data perfectly. The problem is it isn't performing the redirect properly.

What happens is the data posts. "http://exampledomain.com" is left in the address bar, the content of "https://www.pipelinedeals.com/web_lead" loads on the page (and loads in a way that demonstrates it received the posts), then the content of "http://exampledomain.com" loads under it. It's like cURL is pulling in the content of the other page, rather than redirecting the user to it.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It's like cURL is pulling in the content of the other page, rather
>   than redirecting the user to it.

cURL won't actually redirect the user to the page in question. The client's browser is completely oblivious to what cURL is doing. As far as the browser is concerned, it is simply receiving this data back from **your** server (which is executing the POST request).

To solve this, you might want to setup a hidden form and then submit that form via JavaScript. Small example:

```
<form id="pipeline" action="https://www.pipelinedeals.com/web_lead" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="w2lid" value="<?php echo $_POST['w2lid']; ?>">
    <!-- the rest of your POST vars -->
</form>
```

And the JS:

```
document.getElementById('pipeline').submit();
```

Answer (score 1):

Because that is exactly what curl does. It grabs the output of your request, and then you can do some fancy things with it if you like, and then you use that information to render your own page for example.

Are you not looking for: header("Location: http://www.example.com/"); /* Redirect browser */
http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

(possibly together with the CURL of course)

Comment: If I use Header, I can't post the data to PipelineDeals though can I? I can still cURL the posts across, but what the user ends up seeing, will be a version of the page as though the post had not occurred?

Comment: @FerdiaO'Brien The header redirect will act independently of the cURL request so there's no real way to tie the two together.

Comment: Dang. Thanks for the information guys, it looks like it's back to the drawing board. Your suggestion above seems the best way to achieve what I want Wayne.

Comment: In case you're working with GET requests, you can still go for:


`header("location: https://www.pipelinedeals.com/web_lead?developer_mode=DEVMODE&thank_you_page=TYPAGE&w2lid=W2LID&assign_to_id=ASSIGNID&lead[lead_source]=LEADSRC&lead[full_name]=LEADFN&lead[phone]=LEADTEL&lead[email]=LEADMAIL");`

Comment: Unfortunately not Viridis. It must be POST via some methoid. Trust my boss to want Pipeline integration as well as other things :) Thanks for the suggestion though.